# json_decode to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, encoding, json

```
foreach ($likes as $like) {
    // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
    $id = idx($like, 'id');
    $item = idx($like, 'name');

    fwrite($fileout,json_encode($like));
    fwrite($fileout,PHP_EOL );
}

$json_string = file_get_contents('testson.json');
$get_json_values=json_decode($json_string,true);

foreach ($get_json_values as $getlikes) {  ?>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $getlikes['id']; ?>" target="_top">
          </li>
        <?php
      }
```

When opening the browser, there is a `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I don't understand why would my arguments be invalid.

If I add the if, nothing happens, which shows what the actual problem is. But the question is **WHAT IS THE PROPER WAY TO DO THIS**? I'm pretty sure it's very simple, but i've been struggling with this for more than an hour. My json files has fields like this, so I don't think there would be the problem:

```
{"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Yann Tiersen (official)","id":"18359161762"}
```

Please help me, I really got tired with it, and I don't know what to do. So... **how can I decode the file into an array?**

Comment: have you tried, json_decode('data.json', true) ? (the true flag is for array output, instead of an object.

Comment: `foreach()` works equally well on objects as on arrays - if he's getting an `Invalid argument supplied...` error, then he's passing something else (probably boolean false).

Comment: Yes, I have tried the true flag- edited

Comment: @SamDufel yes, but won't work in the case of `$getlikes['id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the contents of the `testson.json` file not just the name!

Receive the contents via PHP:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('testson.json');
```

Make sure there are valid JSON contents in the file by testing it via

```
var_dump(json_decode($json_string));
```

And then call

```
foreach (json_decode($json_string) as $getlikes) {  ?>
```

---

**Update:**
When you save the file and access it miliseconds later it might be that the filesystem is too slow and not showing you the correct content.

Add

```
fclose($fileout);
clearstatcache();
```

before the `file_get_contents();` call!

> I recommend to use `file_put_contents()` and `file_read_contents()` to get
>   rid of such problems!

Comment: Thank you so much! However wouldn't it be better to use `json_decode($json_string,true)`, just in case?

Comment: @BujancaMihai, it would be more clear. But since PHP tries to convert the types of variables into the necessary ones, it works without here. But be save and use the additional parameter `true`!

Comment: The file 'testson.json' is in the same directory as your PHP script? And do you receive the same error or an other one?

Comment: Yes, it is. It actually is encoded by the php, and then decoded again- after some changes

Comment: I shall put more code, maybe it would help. It is firstly encoded, then decoded. I am trying to make a facebook app and I need to encode the file if some commands are given, or to decode, if others are given

Comment: Yes, it is the very same error. The file is not empty, it has about 550 entries

Comment: I have edited the code, please review it, maybe there is any error. Thanks, I will try var_dump

Comment: **Indeed, it is null**. But then is there any way of saving it at runtime, before I try to access it again? Because when I look in the file, it is filled

Comment: lol, i should have thought about it. In c++ I was doing the same thing. Thanks a lot, you saved my day. It works now

Answer (score 1):

json_decode is expecting a string as it's first parameter. You are passing what I'm guessing is a filename. You should load the file first like so...

```
$json = file_get_contents('testson.json');
$data = json_decode($json);
```